# How to delete message with attached .exe file in discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am writing a Discord bot in Python. I need to write an event that will delete the message if the attached file has the extension .exe or .dll, how can I do that?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check extension of file, first you must get the files with `message.attachments`. Then create a loop and check their names.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    for file in message.attachments:
        if file.filename.endswith((".exe", ".dll")):
            await message.delete()
```